# When I make a clone of the object shows me an error message

Tags: javascript, object

First the following is the code of my own javascript library.

```
(function() {
    var lib = {
        elems: [],
        getElem: function() {
            var tmpElem = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
                tmpElem.push(document.getElementById(arguments[i]));
            this.elems = tmpElem;
            tmpElem = null;
            return this;
        },
        html: function(txt) {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.elems.length; i++)
                this.elems[i].innerHTML = txt;
            return this;
        },
        style: function(prob, val) {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.elems.length; i++)
                this.elems[i].style[prob] = val;
            return this;
        },
        addEvent: function(event, callback) {
            if (this.elems[0].addEventListener) {
                for (var i = 0; i < this.elems.length; i++)
                    this.elems[i].addEventListener(event, callback, false);
            } else if (this.elems[0].attachEvent) {
                for (var i = 0; i < this.elems.length; i++)
                    this.elems[i].attachEvent('on' + event, callback);
            }
            return this;
        },
        toggle: function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.elems.length; i++)
                this.elems[i].style.display = (this.elems[i].style.display === 'none' || '') ? 'block' : 'none';
            return this;
        },
        domLoad: function(callback) {
            var isLoaded = false;
            var checkLoaded = setInterval(function() {
                if (document.body && document.getElementById)
                    isLoaded = true;
            }, 10);
            var Loaded = setInterval(function() {
                if (isLoaded) {
                    clearInterval(checkLoaded);
                    clearInterval(Loaded);
                    callback();
                }
            }, 10);
        }
    };

    var fn = lib.getElem;
    for(var i in lib)
        fn[i] = lib[i];

    window.lib = window.$ = fn;
})();
```

Previously, I have used this way to use my own library, and works fine .

```
$.getElem('box').html('Welcome to my computer.');
```

But when updated the code of my own library, and I added

```
var fn = lib.getElem;
for(var i in lib)
   fn[i] = lib[i];
```

To be using the element selector like this way

```
$('box').html('Welcome to my computer.');
```

But the problem began appear when added the updated code to clone the lib object `TypeError: $(...).html is not a function`.

And now I want to use the element selector like that

```
$('box').html('Welcome to my computer.');
```

instead of

```
$.getElem('box').html('Welcome to my computer.');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a variable fn which has a reference to "getElem" but since fn is not a property on your lib object then it means that when getElem refers to "this" it will be you global object which is propbably window.

Remove all the following 3 lines

```
var fn = lib.getElem;
for(var i in lib)
   fn[i] = lib[i];
```

and then do this

```
window.$ = function () { return lib.getElem.apply(lib, arguments); };
```

This will allow getElem to be called as $ but maintaining "lib" as context.

Comment: Thanks, but when using `$('box').html('Welcome to my computer.');`, show me error message `TypeError: $(...) is undefined`.

Comment: Small inquire, why you use return keyword here `return lib.getElem.apply(lib, arguments);` is this for return the statement (`return this;`) that exists in getElem method ?

Comment: Yes. If you did not do this you would not be able to call the ex. the html function "$('box').html(..)".

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve with those additional lines, just by reading the code, `lib.getElem` does not have a function called `html`

`lib` does.

Hence, just `var fn = lib;` should do just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what I want is using the lib selector by using this form `$('box').html('Welcome to my computer.');` instead this form `$.getElem('box').html('Welcome to my computer.');`. but unfortunately, your way not work.

Answer (score 0):

There more ways to achieve this but the root cause is in your `getElem()` function: `return this;`

`$` is a reference to that function. If you call `$()` it is called as a function and not as a method. Therefore `this` refers to `window` and `window` has, of course, no `html()` function.

You could do `return lib;` to fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you please tell me a simple example.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand, an example for what? You can simply replace `getElem: function() { ... return this; }` with `getElem: function() { ... return lib; }` if you mean that.