# When enclose an object by anonymous function, show me error message

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I have the following simple example.

```
(function() { 
var note = {
   show: function() {
        alert('hi');
    }
 };
})();
```

When usage

```
note.show();
```

Show me error message `ReferenceError: note is not defined`.
but when using note object without enclose by anonymous function work fine.

Now, how can I use note object outside anonymous function or in other page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you meant to use something like the module pattern. A very basic example would be:

```
var note = (function() { 
 return {
   show: function() {
        alert('hi');
    }
 };
}());
```

This is only useful if you have closures inside, like:

```
var note = (function() { 
   var someNumber = 10;
   return {
      show: function() {
         alert('hi');
      },
      someNumberTimes(n) {
         return someNumber * n;
      }
   };
}());
console.log(note.someNumberTimes(5)); // 50
```

Comment: Thanks, I have inquire, why the following object who called `lib` in the next link works without doing that instruction that you say it [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16167411/459943)

Comment: Look at the end of that code: `var fn = lib.getElem; /* ... */ window.lib = window.$ = fn;`. The function lib.getElem is exported as a global variable (window.lib, or $).

Comment: Could I use such a way to make note object as a global or I must use your instructions.

Comment: Yes, you can use that, or you can assign to window.note instead of returning (as Minko Gechev suggested on his now-deleted answer). Maybe you don't even need the wrapper function. It all depends on what you're trying to do.